# FullCalendar - selectOverlap prevents creation of allday events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Because [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) function only passes through the event being overlapped, and not the selection, it is difficult to customise how to handle event creation.

In my case, we are working on a calendar/diary system, with background events showing the employee's shifts, and events showing their individual bookings.

At this point, other than the background events - absolutely no events should be able to overlap each other.

However... on top of that - we are then overlaying 'all day events' - which might be any number of things, but for examples sake, let's say they're 'staff birthdays' - therefore, you might have a couple of events today, but there will be an event in the all day section, showing someone's birthday.

I am checking for `eventOverlap` and doing some other checks on `eventDrop` and `eventResize` which handle different clashes, but these only work for existing events being moved or resized. I would like to do the same on event creation - which happens during the select. In order to disallow the select of spaces which already have events, I am using the example function from the `selectOverlap` documentation:

```
function(event) {
    return event.rendering === 'background';
}
```

This works fantastically. However, if I try to create a new All Day event, it will 'overlap' any other events that exist on that day, and not pass this check.
I was hoping to be able to use the selection's object to check it for an `allDay=true`, but the function is only passed the existing event, and there is no way to check the selected section.

You can see a very simplified demo here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQrxOO

Try to create an allday event on the day which already has events.

Is there a better way to do this? I can completely remove the `selectOverlap` and do everything in the [select callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) instead, but I would need to essentially duplicate the overlap checks just to make this work, and I feel like that seems like overkill for something that should be relatively simple.

Is it possible to get not only the overlapped event object, but also the selection object when doing a `selectOverlap` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current workaround is to remove the `selectOverlap` check, and instead do it myself within the `select callback`.

Below is a simplified version of a quick function I wrote to call when using `select={this.handleEventCreate}`:

```
class Diary extends React.Component {

    //additional functions, state definitions, etc etc etc here.

    //Define calendarRef as it will be needed in the function below
    calendarRef = React.createRef();


    handleEventCreate = (info) => {
        // Get the Calendar API to allow unselection
        let calendarApi = this.calendarRef.current.getApi();

        // Get all Events
        let checkEvents = calendarApi.getEvents();
        // Loop through them
        checkEvents.forEach(function(event){
            // If it's not a background element, check whether the new element contains the existing, or vice versa.
            if(event.rendering !== "inverse-background" && 
                    (
                        (event.start >= info.start && event.start <= info.end) ||
                        (event.end >= info.start && event.end <= info.end) ||
                        (info.start >= event.start && info.start <= event.end) ||
                        (info.end >= event.start && info.end <= event.end)
                    )
                ){
                    // It is an overlapping event, so we reject it.
                    return calendarApi.unselect();
                }
        });

        alert('All good here to create the event.');
        //extra event creation code to fire here.
    }
```

Comment: As of July 2019, this is the recommended way to do this (handling the `selectOverlap` within the `select callback`. I have raised a feature request to get the `selectOverlap` function to receive the new event as well as the overlapped event to make this easier in the future: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4792

Comment: Any ideas on how to get this.calendarRef when calling a method using FullCalendar Vue? Ta

Comment: Hi @raison - I don't, as I am using ReactJS for this, but it could be quite similar - this.calendarRef is defined within the class as well as simply `calendarRef = React.createRef();` - will update the answer above to show a little more detail.

Comment: Note also that `calendarRef` is a variable I named myself - you won't find it in fullCalendar - but in my case it references `React.createRef()`.